# REST Authentication: put key in custom header or Authorization header?

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

I'm designing a REST API framework for a large security-conscious company.

Every caller to our services needs to provide a client key to access the system. We will use that for authorizing access for that particular client as well as rate limiting and monitoring. Also *some* of our API calls will access customer data, and we will use OAuth 2 tokens to control access to that data.

My question is how to pass the client key. I can not use HTTP Basic Authentication or a query parameter because we cannot pass it in the URI (URIs get logged sometimes) -- it must be in an HTTP header instead. So I have thought of two approaches, both with flaws:

(1) Invent our own header: `MyCompanyAPIKey: api-key-goes-here`. This is flawed because we will be inventing our own header and that's a poor design choice. It won't work with anyone else or with standard tools (because we invented our own).

(2) Use the Authorization header: `Authorization: Bearer api-key-goes-here`. This is flawed because it will conflict with OAuth (which needs that header) in the cases where we use that. Technically I suppose we don't *need* the client key when we have an OAuth token (since the OAuth token was specific to a single client), but I don't know if the normal tools can handle that.

How do you think we should proceed?

Comment: FYI, you can pass HTTP Basic Auth credentials in the header. You don't have to to pass them in the URI

Comment: @KTastrophy Ooh... I didn't realize that. Let me go read some RFCs.

Comment: @KTastrophy [somewhat later] No... according to RFC2617, it uses the "Authorization" header, so that doesn't help.

Comment: OK, so you want to know how you can consistently pass an API key that may or may not be along side an OAuth authenticated request?

Comment: Also, what "normal tools" are you speaking of?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass an API key and I might also want to pass an OAuth token. (The one authenticating the client application and the other providing evidence that it is authorized to access a particular end user's data.) And by "normal tools" I mean, rather roughly, stuff I might use. Like Apigee or Mashery. Or anything corresponding the the JAX-RS standard for Java. Basically, the reason to follow standards is so your things will work with other tools out there and I'm concerned about achieving that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your requirements, its sounds like a custom header is the way to go here.

I believe your concern regarding it being a poor design choice is irrelevant here because there is no standardized way of passing an API key. API keys mean different things to different applications. To some, its a user id; to others, its a password; and to others still it's simply means of throttling where no explicit authentication is even required.

As far as compatibility goes, most tools, allow some flexibility regarding working with API so as long is you don't do anything crazy I think you'll be fine. Whatever you do, just make sure  that with any standards you do choose to implement that you implement them fully (OAuth vs "OAuth like") and provide documentation.